# Convert dates with mysql, Microsoft 1900 Date system

Tags: mysql, sql, date

A subsystem (which I don't have control over) exports data to a mysql table and stores dates in number of days from 1900 (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/180162). I need those dates returned as a unix time stamp.

Example of two dates

```
SELECT date FROM my_table WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2
41315,3921180556
41321,7267013889
```

Desired output

```
SELECT some_magic(date) FROM my_table WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2
1360488279
1361035587
```

I could not find any [date-and-time-functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that does the job. Have I missed something?

I want the output from a SELECT of dates to be delivered as this PHP function I wrote.

```
function UnMicrosoftify($fDateValue = 0, $iDateBase = 1900) {
    if ($iDateBase == 1900) {
        $iMyDateBase = 25569;

        //Adjust for the fictional 29-Feb-1900 (Day 60)
        if ($fDateValue < 60) {
            --$iMyDateBase;
        }
    } else {
        $iMyDateBase = 24107;
    }

    // Perform conversion
    if ($fDateValue >= 1) {
        $utcDays = $fDateValue - $iMyDateBase;
        $iReturnValue = round($utcDays * 86400);
        if (($iReturnValue <= PHP_INT_MAX) && ($iReturnValue >= -PHP_INT_MAX)) {
            $iReturnValue = (integer) $iReturnValue;
        }
    } else {
        $hours = round($fDateValue * 24);
        $mins = round($fDateValue * 1440) - round($hours * 60);
        $secs = round($fDateValue * 86400) - round($hours * 3600) - round($mins * 60);
        $iReturnValue = (integer) gmmktime($hours, $mins, $secs);
    }
    return $iReturnValue;
}

echo UnMicrosoftify((float) str_replace(',','.', "41315,3921180556")) //displays 1360488279 (ie 2013-02-10 09:24:39)
echo UnMicrosoftify((float) str_replace(',','.', "41321,7267013889")) //displays 1361035587 (ie 2013-02-16 17:26:27)
```

Is it possible to do this with mysql? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the date is stored as a varchar you have to cast it to a decimal of suitable precision and then it should work as shown in the first version; if it's already a decimal the second version works.

Try this, I think it is what you want:

```
SELECT 
  date AS ExcelSerialDate,

  ADDDATE(ADDDATE(ADDDATE('1899-12-31 00:00',
                          cast(replace(date,',','.') as  DECIMAL(30,12))), 
                INTERVAL -1 DAY), INTERVAL (MOD(date,1) * 86400) SECOND) 
  AS ConvDate,

  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    ADDDATE(
      ADDDATE(
        ADDDATE('1899-12-31 00:00',
                cast(replace(date,',','.') as  DECIMAL(30,12))), 
        INTERVAL -1 DAY), 
      INTERVAL (
        MOD(cast(replace(date,',','.') as  DECIMAL(30,12)),1) * 86400
      ) SECOND
    )
  ) 
  AS UnixTS_From_varchar,

  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
    ADDDATE(
      ADDDATE(
        ADDDATE('1899-12-31 00:00',date2), 
        INTERVAL -1 DAY), 
      INTERVAL (
        MOD(date2,1) * 86400
      ) SECOND
    )
  ) 
  AS UnixTS_from_double    

FROM my_table;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5d2c/25)

With your sample data this gives:

```
EXCELSERIALDATE     CONVDATE             UNIXTS_FROM_VARCHAR UNIXTS_FROM_DOUBLE
41315,3921180556    2013-02-10 00:00:00  1360488279          1360488279
41321,7267013889    2013-02-17 00:00:00  1361121987          1361121987
```